# joda time unexpected format

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, datetime-parsing

I'm trying to use Joda-Time library to convert a `String` date and time to `Date` but the result I get is not the expected.

From the server I get:

> 08/11/2017 12:30
>   10/11/2017 12:30

Joda converts it to:

> 2017-01-08T12:30:00.000+02:00
>   2017-01-10T12:30:00.000+02:00

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

// add two :00 at the end for the seconds
startDate = startDate +":00";
DateTime start = formatter.parseDateTime(startDate);
System.out.println(start.toString());

endDate= endDate + ":00";
DateTime end = formatter.parseDateTime(endDate);
```

Comment: 08/11/2017 12:30   === > 2017-01-08T12:30:00.000+02:00       and                                          10/11/2017 12:30   === > 2017-01-10T12:30:00.000+02:00

Comment: The pattern "dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss" is surely not okay because the first occurrence of "mm" should rather be "MM" (month, not minute).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're using `mm` for the month, but the correct pattern is **uppercase** `MM`. Check the [documentation](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) for more details.

One more thing. If your input doesn't have the seconds (`:00`), you don't need to append it in the end of the input strings. You can simply create a pattern without it:

```java
// "MM" for month, and don't use "ss" for seconds if input doesn't have it
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");

// parse input (without ":00" for the seconds)
DateTime start = formatter.parseDateTime("08/11/2017 12:30");
System.out.println(start.toString());
```

The output will be:

> 2017-11-08T12:30:00.000-02:00

Notice that the offset (`-02:00`) is different from yours. That's because `DateTime` uses the default timezone if you don't specify one.